# Cannot bind empty textbox to nullable decimal with MVVM light

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light

Is there any solution to binding a textbox to a nullable decimal? Whenever you leave the textbox empty the binding is not updated. I know one solution is to use a string property instead but I really don't want to do it that way.

Answer (score 17):

You can do the trick by using [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx).

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If simple bindings won't do you can always use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).